# multilevel angular js dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

Im using the dropdown [angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect). But it has only a single level dropdown. This can be used to show the following response.

```
[
    { id: 1, label: 'Facility 01' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Facility 02' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Facility 03' },
    { id: 4, label: 'Facility 04' },
    { id: 5, label: 'Facility 05' },
    { id: 6, label: 'Facility 06' },
    { id: 7, label: 'Facility 07' },
    { id: 8, label: 'Facility 08' },
];
```

But what i need is a multilevel dropdown to show the followind response in the dropdown.

```
[
  {
    "id": 8,
    "label": "AA",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "label": "BB",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 10,
            "label": "DD",
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "label": "CC",
        "items": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to display the above response using [angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect). Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution for you question here.
plnkr.co/edit/gHzV9d?p=preview

Comment: i used the bootstrap dropdown u just mentioned. i want the same feature in the dropdown im using right now. cant use bootstrap dropdown because i dont know the complete working of it and im new to angular